# AngularJS state loading

Tags: angularjs, angular-ui-router, angular-ui-router-extras

I'm trying to load states dynamically from a JSON file using `ui-router-extras`. The JSON file looks like the following:

```js
    [
  {
    "name": "app",
    "url": "/app",
    "abstract": "true",
    "resolve": "helper.resolveFor('fastclick', 'modernizr', 'icons')"
    
  },
  {
    "name": "login",
    "url": "/login",
    "title": "User Login",
    "templateUrl": "",
    "redirectToLogin": "true"
  },
  {
    "name": "dashboard",
    "url": "/dashboard",
    "title": "Dashboard",
    "templateUrl": "helper.basepath('dashboard.html')",
    "resolve": "helper.resolveFor('flot-chart', 'flot-chart-plugins', 'weather-icons')"
   
  }
]
```

The following is the routes config file:

```
(function () {
'use strict';

angular
    .module('app.routes')
    .config(routesConfig);

routesConfig.$inject = ['$stateProvider', '$locationProvider', '$urlRouterProvider', 'RouteHelpersProvider', '$stateProvider', '$futureStateProvider'];
function routesConfig($stateProvider, $locationProvider, $urlRouterProvider, helper, $sp, $fsp) {

    $locationProvider.html5Mode(false);

    var futureStateResolve = function($http) { 
        return $http.get("states.json").then(function (response) {
            console.log(response.data);
            angular.forEach(response.data, function (state) {

                $sp.state(state);
                })
            })
        }
    $fsp.addResolve(futureStateResolve);

         // defaults to dashboard
    $urlRouterProvider.otherwise('/app/login');
    }
})();
```

The `/login` state works ok, but the others don't work and give the error 'invocables must be object'. I think this is because `helper.basepath()` and `helper.resolveFor()` functions are not working, as they are coming as strings from the JSON.

What should I do?

Comment: as for the function pass it as 2 properties...function name and arguments

Comment: my bad...just need array of args for resolve  `{"resolve": "['flot-chart', 'flot-chart-plugins', 'weather-icons']...}`  ... then pass array and use apply() .... `helper.resolveFor.apply(null, obj.resolve)`

Comment: But since I'm reading from json, where should be the change? As not all the states have resolve property.

Comment: well you will need some conditionals. What is the reason for doing all this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

My advice is the same as @charlietfli.   I will elaborate.

Since you have already created a helper function that returns your resolve block, you can easily work around the fact that JSON doesn't support JS code or expressions.

Your helper function takes a list of strings as arguments.  JSON supports arrays of strings.  Change your JSON from this: `"resolve": "helper.resolveFor('fastclick', 'modernizr', 'icons')"` to this: `"resolve": ["fastclick", "modernizr", "icons"]`.  Now, the JSON resolve contains a simple array of strings.

When you load the states, first convert the array to a resolve block using your helper, and then register them.

```
var futureStateResolve = function($http) { 
    return $http.get("states.json").then(function (response) {
        angular.forEach(response.data, function (state) {
            // The array of strings from the JSON
            var stringArgs = state.resolve;
            // If present, convert to a resolve: object and put back on the state definition
            if (stringArgs) state.resolve = helper.resolveFor.apply(helper, stringArgs);
            $sp.state(state);
        })
    })
}
$fsp.addResolve(futureStateResolve);
```

---

That should answer your question.

However, I noticed you are using future states from ui-router-extras, but you are not lazy loading the code (controllers or whole javascript angular modules) itself.  Normally, you register future states with the `$futureStateProvider`, and not directly with the `$stateProvider`.    There's nothing wrong with what you are doing (lazy loading the state definitions and taking advantage of deferred ui-router bootstrap from Future States).  However, you could achieve the same thing without depending on the ui-router-extras library.

This is how you would lazily add state definitions without ui-router-extras:

[Angular - UI Router - programmatically add states](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/25866387/angular-ui-router-programmatically-add-states/25872852#25872852)

This is how you can defer ui-router from parsing the url until you are done adding state definitions:

[Angular ui-router and ocLazyLoad](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/30765685/angular-ui-router-and-oclazyload/30902498#30902498)